# Is the chrome support for Web Bluetooth still not very widespread on different Android 6/7 devices?

Tags: google-chrome, android-bluetooth, web-bluetooth

I'm working on supporting a Bluetooth Low Energy device from a web application running on Chrome on Android.  I have no problems communicating from my Samsung phone, but the Tablet I have just says "Could not connnect to Bluetooth device!" when testing on the page https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/demos/bluetooth-printer/ .

When I look at chrome://bluetooth-internals, the Discoverable and Discovering were disabled even though Bluetooth is turned on.  I can't find any information about why Discoverable and Discovering would be disabled.

The tablet is a Lenovo 4 Tab 10 (Model TB-x304L) with Android 7.1.1, the device is supposed to support Bluetooth 4.1 and BLE.

Is the chrome support for Web Bluetooth still not very widespread on different devices, despite BLE being out for a while?